# Is there a open source CRM system for Telegram management

Tags: open-source, python

I am currently in search of an open-source software solution that can assist me in effectively managing users for my Telegram channel. My goal is to streamline the process of handling user access and reminders through the use of a bot, eliminating the need for manual maintenance through spreadsheets. If you are aware of any suitable software that can fulfill this requirement, I would greatly appreciate your advice and recommendations. Open-source software options would be particularly valuable in this context. Greatly appreciate any help you can provide